# Rewrite rules for multiple files

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We've just launched a new site and have found that there are multiple Google errors in the WebMaster tools that we need to fix. We've redirected the major pages with redirect 301 before launching but want to rewrite 500+ errors for strings/directories/etc where the files don't exist.

Errors look like this:

- /product.php?id=143 (multiple IDs)
- /page.php?id=109 (multiple IDs)
- /product_42-productname.htm (multiple product names)

Can we do a catchall type redirect where any page that starts with /product goes to a single page?

We're running a Wordpress site so current htaccess has:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>'
```

Would we need to include it as part of that statement or later in the htaccess file?

We've tried many options but don't want to have to list every item in the htaccess and just can't get our heads around how to fix this easily???

Any help most appreciated.

Ta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can catch the offending "product" links and redirect to *index.php*, your homepage instead. The rule would come before your wordpress rules as shown below.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(product|page) /index.php? [R,L]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The rule would catch the links irrespective of what query parameters (ids) it comes in with.

Comment: Thx Ravi, this works but leaves a trailing ID on the end. E.g. /product.php?id=143 becomes www.example.com.au//?id=143.

Is it an easy change to delete the ID query?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty simple. Just change index.php to index.php? as shown in my update. You can also change R to R=301 in case you wanna do a 301 permanent redirect.